# Youtube oembed works just fine, but not always. Why?

Tags: php, json, curl, youtube

I am using PHP curl to get the thumbnail (and more) for youtube videos and most of the time it works but not always.

This one works:
Interstellar Flight - Preview 
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JT_-KjeWYE&format=json

But this one doesnt:
Marvel's "Avengers: Age of Ultron" - Teaser Trailer (OFFICIAL) 
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmeOjFno6Do&format=json

The one that doesnt work is embeddable:
http://jsfiddle.net/95ncp1o4/

I get not errors.

Code I'm using:

```
(preg_match('/(?<=youtu.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?=v|vi|\?v=|\?vi=|watch\?v=|watch\?vi=))/', $url)) {

 (preg_match('/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\'>]+)/', $url, $matches));

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url='.urlencode($url).'&format=json';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($c);

if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {

 echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

} else {

 $title = $json->title;
 $thumbnail_url = $json->thumbnail_url;
 $author_name = $json->author_name;
 $author_url = $json->author_url;

return '
  <div class="youtube"><div class="src">youtube.com</div>
    <div class="youtube_thmbnl"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $matches[1] . '"><img src="' . $thumbnail_url . '"></a></div>
    <div class="youtube_title">' . $title . '</div>
    <div class="youtube_author">By: <a href="' . $author_url . '">' . $author_name . '</a></div>
  </div>';

}

curl_close($ch);
```

So my question why doesnt some work and others do not? Both urls show up fine in my browser...